# Can someone explain how endpoints function works?

Tags: r, time-series, xts, endpoint

I don't understand why I receive an output from endpoints function, whereas I am expecting something else. I wrote a pseudo code, could someone explain the mechanism?

```
y1<-rep(1,times=750)
y1<-xts(y1, order.by = Sys.Date()-1:750)
endpoints(y1,'days',250)
```

With this code R returns  `0 123 347 484 713 750`. Shouldn't it return `250 500 750` ? Or how would it return those indices?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `endpoints` always generates a point at the end of the year and that `k` is counted from the beginning of the year on :

```
y1[endpoints(y1,'days',k=250)]
           [,1]
2019-09-07    1
2019-12-31    1
2020-09-06    1
2020-12-31    1
2021-02-06    1
```

Above result is either 250th day of year or end of year.
Didn't find an explicit mention to this in documentation, but source code shows that `year` plays a key role even if counting `days`:

```
days = {
    ixyday <- posixltindex$year * 1000L + 1900000L + posixltindex$yday
    .Call("endpoints", ixyday, 1L, k, addlast, PACKAGE = "xts")
  }
```

To get the indexes you are looking for, you could use `%%` (modulo operator):

```
which(1:750%%250==0)
[1] 250 500 750
```

Comment: @Tamas F, did it  answer your question?